# Django 3.0 Not Found: /favicon.ico and failing to store uploaded image into disk

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am a newbie to Django development and developing an app where users can upload their details and profile picture. The uploaded picture is failed to store in the disk and showing an error. please help me out. **[EDITED]**

```
Not Found: /favicon.ico
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53590)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\venkatesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\venkatesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\venkatesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\venkatesh\Envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\venkatesh\Envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "c:\users\venkatesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Here is my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('signup/',views.register,name='signup'),
    path('signup/register',views.register,name='signup'),
    path('signin/',views.signin,name='signin'),
    path('signin/signin',views.signin,name='signin'),
    path('logout/',views.logout,name='logout'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for AI project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '4+12aq#j(k%zq%(b%)o2&ln=2ex7-dykjo-(=hk1m3dxj2#&dtz_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Bharatha',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'AI.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'AI.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'2208',
        'HOST':'localhost'

    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ) 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URl = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import Profile_Form
from .models import ResgisterFrom


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'base.html')


def signin(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password= request.POST['password']

        user =auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Invalid Credentials!')
            return redirect('signin')
    else:

        return render(request,'signin.html')

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('/')

def register(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    template = 'register.html'
   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        #form = Profile_Form(request.POST)
        form = Profile_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            if User.objects.filter(username=form.cleaned_data['username']).exists():
                return render(request, template, {
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Username already exists.'
                })
            elif User.objects.filter(email=form.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
                return render(request, template, {
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Email already exists.'
                })
            elif form.cleaned_data['password'] != form.cleaned_data['password_repeat']:
                return render(request, template, {
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Passwords do not match.'
                })
            else:
                # Create the user:
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    form.cleaned_data['username'],
                    form.cleaned_data['email'],
                    form.cleaned_data['password']
                )
                user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                user.phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
                user.photo = request.FILES['photo']
                user.save()
                

                return redirect('signin')
               

   # No post data available, let's just show the page.
    else:
        form = Profile_Form()

    return render(request, template, {'form': form})

class EmpImageDisplay(DetailView):
    model = ResgisterFrom
    template_name = 'base.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'
```

here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class ResgisterFrom(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password_repeat = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a typo in `settings.py` - it should be `MEDIA_URL` (all caps) not `MEDIA_URl`. I don't know whether that will fix the problem - please include the full traceback so that we can see where the error is occurring.

Comment: You've revealed your `SECRET_KEY` from your settings -- make sure that you change it before you deploy your site.

Comment: @Alasdair. The error is solved. Thanks for admitting about scret key. Now another issue uploaded picture is not storing into disk, please help me out

Comment: If you've got a new problem, then please start a new question. You've marked this answer as accepted, so people won't realise that you still need an answer.

Comment: Note that you can see your old secret key in [the history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63149037/revisions) - that's why I suggested changing it in your code, not in your question.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdir reminding about secret key. This app won't go into production because still I am a learner. Ok, I will start another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your settings.py
You should add `/`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')
```